# If an XML file contains several nodes with same name on different level, how to specify the exact node want to get?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have encounter an problem with using javascript/jquery to read XML file's nodes.

Say We have a xml file like this

```
<root>
  <people>
    <name>Jack</name>
    <age>18</age>
  </people>
  <name>Rose</name>
</root>
```

For this xml file, on the first level, there is a name with content"Rose", and in the second level there are also has a name with content"Jack"

I have tried to use jquery's function to read the file:

```
var NAME;
$.get('myxml.xml', 'xml', function(d){
    NAME = $(d).find('name').text();
});
```

But in this way, everytime the NAME will contain the combine of two node's contents, like 'JackRose'

If I just want to get the contents of the second node, the 'Rose' one to be read and stored, what should I do?

Thank you!

Comment: `.eq(1).text()` should get you `"Rose"`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `each` method:

```
$.get('myxml.xml', 'xml', function(d){
    $(d).find('name').each(function(){
        var txt = $(this).text()
    });
});
```

Or `eq` method:

```
$.get('myxml.xml', 'xml', function(d){
    var $name = $(d).find('name');
    var first = $name.eq(0).text()        
    var second = $name.eq(1).text()
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
var NAME;
$.get('myxml.xml', 'xml', function(d){
    NAME = $(d).find('root > name').text();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

As the second one is a direct child of the `root` element it can be found like this:

```
var NAME;
$.get('myxml.xml', 'xml', function(d){
    NAME = $(d).find('> name').text();
});
```

Depending on the xml, if the root element is'nt really the `root` element, and often there is a `<xml>` element as the root element, the selector would be `('root > name')` !